# Преобразование массива данных

Tags: javascript

Необходимо преобразовать массив вида:

```
[
    {
        name: 'John',
        data: { /* Данные */ }
    },
    {
        name: 'John',
        data: { /* Данные */ }
    },
    {
        name: 'John',
        data: { /* Данные */ }
    },
    {
        name: 'Tom',
        data: { /* Данные */ }
    },
    {
        name: 'Tom',
        data: { /* Данные */ }
    }
]
```

В такой:

```
[
    {
        name: 'John',
        data: [
            { /* Данные */ },
            { /* Данные */ },
            { /* Данные */ }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Tom',
        data: [
            { /* Данные */ },
            { /* Данные */ }
        ]
    }
]
```

Сделать это нужно одним действием чем менее императивно тем лучше. У меня получился вот такой вариант, но я не уверен что это оптимальное решение.

```
const list = list.reduce((accum, curent)=> {
    const name = curent.name
    const isExist = accum.some(el=>el.name === name)

    if(accum.length === 0 || !isExist) {
        accum.push({
            name,
            data: []
        })
    }
    return accum.map((el) => {
        if(el.name === name) {
            el.data.push(curent.data)                   
        }
        return el
    })
}, [])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const person = [
  { name: 'John', data: { 1: 'Данные' } },
  { name: 'John', data: { 2: 'Данные' } },
  { name: 'John', data: { 3: 'Данные' } },
  { name: 'Tom', data: { 1: 'Данные' } },
  { name: 'Tom', data: { 2: 'Данные' } }
]

function merge(arrData) {
  return Array.prototype.filter.call(arrData, function (v) {
    return this.has(v.name) ?
      (this.get(v.name).push(v.data), false) :
      (this.set(v.name, (v.data = [v.data])), true)
  }, new Map())
}
console.log(merge(person))
```

Comment: в чем смысл `Array.prototype.filter.call` если в arrData массив?

Comment: что-то я не пойму, почему минусы у ответа... Разве что функцию можно было бы назвать понятней, типа `groupByName`, и использование фильтра не очень понятно. Но на мой взгляд это не стоит минуса -- код-то вполне рабочий, похож на эффективный и лаконичный.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin :) это не минусы, а банальная месть: за неспособность дать более лаконичный ответ и одновременно аргументировать "что тут не так". Прилетели оба ночью, почти в одно время, и без комментариев. А что с фильтром непонятно: самое эффективное использовать параллельно `Map`, никаких промежуточных разборов и только один проход - он дает возможность раскидать ссылки на массивы для каждого ключа `v.name, (v.data = [v.data])`. Привязываем его к `filter` через `this` и полностью избавляемся от дополнительной инициализации переменных.

Comment: Я бы добавил параметр с именем свойства, по которому необходимо группировать. А так решение красивое и лаконичное.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko согласен, было бы не лишним. Чтоб не менять оригинал, добавим здесь `(arrData, field='name')`.